# CMV Viewer Floating Widgets

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer, widget

Does anyone have an example CMV site without the side bar or any indication whether it would be worth pursuing CMV if what I need is all widgets to be Floating Title Panes?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without some extensive reworking of CMV's layout and widget loading.

"CMV 2.0" is conceptually underway. https://github.com/cmv/cmv-labs Very early stages, but a core concept is the layout as a widget. You could have a full page map layout widget with floating panes.

Comment: Ah OK. I suspected as much. I'll check out the CMV 2..0 project, but perhaps I need to boldly take my own path here :o\

Answer (score 1):

I did something with CMV that you might be interested in. I created a toolbar across the top. And, I created a custom container type for non-dialog widgets. It's a commercial product. Here's a link to one of our sites:
http://lakeinsurveyor.mygisonline.com/?_h=true
The Floating Panel did require minor core changes, but the menu didn't. I'll try to find time to get the menu packaged as a widget.

Edit: One more thing. I tried to totally remove the sliding drawer. I was successful, but I found that there were still some side-effects. So, we kept the drawer, and people thought it was "cool".

Comment: Ah well. I'll have to start from scratch I think as the sidebar is not suitable for my project.